# Can you handle array sections in C++ in a similar fashion as modern fortran?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say *A* is a 9x9 array. If I want to copy the contents of row 4 into the 1x9 array *V*, in fortran (90 or later) this can be done as

```
    V = A(:,4)
```

One could also access elements 4 through 8 in V with

```
    W = V(5:8)
```

or perhaps have a 2x5 subarray of A:

```
    S = A(3:4, 5:9)
```

This is only a matter of accessing stored values so it causes very little overhead.

Isn't there something as straightforward in C++? What should I *#include* at the beginning of my code to have similar array handling capabilities?

Comment: With iterators it's of course possible to get a range of elements from an array.  But for anything else you need to create a set of classes to support the functionality, it's not possible in standard C++ or its library.

Comment: Probably [`submdspan`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2630r0.html), but that's not for today.

Comment: @Nelfeal I see. It's proposed for a future C++revision. Why don't you turn it into an answer? I quote: "Creating subspans is an integral capability of many, if not all programming languages with multidimensional arrays. These include Fortran, Matlab, Python, and Python’s NumPy extension.". I might not be the first person with this question after all.

Comment: There are multiple solutions in common template libraries. In Boost you could use [multidimensional array views](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_generators)

Comment: Check out this post for an example of slicing multi_arrays
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62701571/1328439

Comment: @DimaChubarov I didn't know about Boost (I'm in the very beginning) but I see it seems to be the closest thing to a standard. You might want to elaborate your comment a bit into an answer. It seems useful.

Comment: You could use valarray with slice() for a 1-d array, or gslice() for a quasi-2d array.

Comment: This comment doesn't scale well: "This is only a matter of accessing stored values so it causes very little overhead." That is, the specific examples you have shown cause deep data copies, which for huge variables is a *lot* of overhead. Simple code like this can easily bog down a program when faced with very large variables. In such cases it often pays off to write code that points back to the original slices whenever possible to avoid the deep data copies.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposal for [`std::submdspan`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2630r0.html), building on [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan), hopefully to be included in C++23. If I undestand correctly, this is exactly what you would want:

> the subspan or “slicing” function that returns a view of a subset of an existing `mdspan`
> ...
> Creating subspans is an integral capability of many, if not all programming languages with multidimensional arrays. These include **Fortran**, Matlab, Python, and Python’s NumPy extension.

So there is nothing "as straightforward" in standard C++ yet, but it might come soon. However, you could use a third-party library or just write a simpler version of it using iterators.